# Grails: ShiroSecurity - log in user without UsernamePasswordToken

Tags: authentication, grails, shiro

The usual way of authenticating user is to invoke:

SecurityUtils.subject.login(new UsernamePasswordToken(params.username, params.password))

However, what if I would like to log him in automagically, without necessity of typing username and password? I have created method in userService like this:

```
   def logIn(User user){
    Object userIdentity = user.email
    String realmName = "ShiroDbRealm";
    PrincipalCollection principals = new SimplePrincipalCollection(userIdentity, realmName);
    Subject subject = new Subject.Builder().principals(principals).buildSubject();
    ThreadContext.bind(subject)
   }
```

But this does not work, any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue. I have created my own class that implements AuthenticationToken interface:

```
class UsernameToken implements AuthenticationToken{

  private username;

  public UsernameToken(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getPrincipal() {
    return username;
  }
  public String getCredentials() {
    return username;
  }
}
```

and created new Realm which looks exactly the same as the default one but without password verification. Now I can use

```
SecurityUtils.subject.login(new UsernameToken(user.username))
```